# Packing bitmaps

Tags: c++, bitmap, textures, packing, bin-packing

I am trying to pack font glyph images into a single texture. The bitmaps are 1 byte per pixel monochromatic and I wish to pack them all together onto 1 texture. I am able to calculate the minimum texture size required but I am unable to manage an algorithm to packing them all together.

I currently have the bitmaps stored as char pointers and I am able to get the dimensions of each.

Comment: Are your glyphs all the same font size?

Comment: By "1 byte per pixel monochromatic", did you mean 1 **bit** per pixel?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "texture"? Do you just mean a single large image?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any question in this question.

Comment: "What algorithm should I use to pack them all together" seems to be the implied question.

Comment: It is a 1 byte per pixel monochromatic and yes, I wish to store them all into 1 larger image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert in bin packing, but here's a simple algorithm you may try.

1. Order glyphs from tallest to shortest. The tallest glyphs will be placed first.
2. Let H be the height of the next tallest unplaced glyph.
3. Expand your texture vertically by adding a level of height H.
4. Fill the level with the remaining glyphs (tallest to shortest) until there is no room left for the next glyph.
5. Goto #2

This is known as [Next-Fit Decreasing Height (NFDH)](http://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/C.L.Mumford/heidi/Approaches.html) algorithm. An interactive demo can be seen [here](http://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/C.L.Mumford/heidi/NFDHquarters.html).

Since your glyphs are more or less the same height, I think this simple algorithm should give you good results.

Check out this [survey](http://www.csc.liv.ac.uk/~epa/surveyhtml.html) for more algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Simple packing algorithm can be found here: http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/lightmaps/

It is called "Guillotine pack" in Jukka Jylänki's paper "A Thousand Ways To Pack the Bin".

The pseudo-code at blackpawn.com is really simple.

There are also related answers for similar questions:
[Piece together several images into one big image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125620/piece-together-several-images-into-one-big-image)