# Pack images into a larger image

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, packing

There are images (literally, PNG files), they come in different sizes and need to be put together into a larger image, so that (1) they don’t overlap, and (2) the amount of unused pixels is minimal.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I can imagine that packing rectangles is nothing new, but honestly, I cannot find neither an implementation nor an algorithm for this.

Comment: When I google for **rectangle packing algorithm**, I get quite a few results, including [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem).

Comment: Searching for 'rectangle packing' gives http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125620/piece-together-several-images-into-one-big-image and http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/lightmaps/default.html (and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153123/packing-rectangles-for-compact-representation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one algorithm: [Fast optimizing rectangle packing algorithm for building CSS sprites](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/rectanglepacker.aspx). The article includes an explanation and C# code. It also links to a [paper](http://www.aaai.org/Papers/ICAPS/2003/ICAPS03-029.pdf) that might be interesting.